# Is it possible to set up multiple startup projects programatically on .NET Core?

Tags: iis, .net-core, startup

I have a Web API project and an authentication project built on .NET Core and I set up several startups in Visual Studio to run the project when starting IIS. What to try to figure out is if there is any way to do this programming and not from visual studio. My idea is when running the API, somehow refer to another project (in my case the authentication server) at the API startup or elsewhere and this one runs both projects (as happens when setting up multiple startups in Visual Studio).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Quick suggestion. 

You should edit this fix the typos and see if you can make the question clearer. I was going to edit it for you, but I didn't understand the question in your last sentence.

Comment: In visual studio you can run two projects at once. (right click solution, properties, select the projects you want to run). As far as I know you can't programmatically run two projects

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019

Comment: Followed that link, not working for me... :(